# I need a little help wth using tkinter and pillow(Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library, gif

I am new to coding so problem might be very simple but I just dont get it.
So I am trying to upload a gif image to tkinter label. Here is my code:

---

```
from PIL import *
import PIL.Image
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
img = PIL.Image.open ("10.gif")
tkimage = PhotoImage(img)
label = Label(root, image=tkimage)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

And here is the error that I am getting:

```
 __str__ returned non-string (type GifImageFile)
```

I dont seem to find answer from google for this particular problem(I have tried)

Comment: You don't need PIL for .gif images, `PhotoImage()` can read them directly.  And if you are going to use PIL, you use `ImageTk` instead of `Image`, and don't use `PhotoImage` at all.

Comment: jasonharper should your comment not be an answer?

Comment: Have I understood wrong or does tkinter support gif animations or does it just pick up the first frame from gif?

Comment: Tkinter just shows the first frame by default, but you can access any frame so you can display an animated gif with some additional code that loops through and displays all frames one at a time.